# Not able to access kafka using service IP

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-service

To deploy Kafka with Zookeeper we are using below yaml code.
Kafka is running successfully and we are able to write and read data on Kafka topic through pod IP, but we are not able to write to Kafka topic through service IP.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-cluster1
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-cluster1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper-cluster1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: zookeeper-cluster1
        app: zookeeper-cluster1
    spec:
      hostname: zookeeper-cluster1
      containers:
      - name: zookeeper-cluster1
        image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
        - containerPort: 2888
        - containerPort: 3888

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-cluster1
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-cluster1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: zookeeper-cluster1
  ports:
  - name: zookeeper-cluster1
    protocol: TCP
    port: 2181
    targetPort: 2181
  - name: zookeeper-follower-cluster1
    protocol: TCP
    port: 2888
    targetPort: 2888
  - name: zookeeper-leader-cluster1
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3888
    targetPort: 3888

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka-cluster
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: kafka-cluster
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-cluster
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: kafka-cluster
        app: kafka-cluster
    spec:
      hostname: kafka-cluster
      containers:
      - name: kafka-cluster
        image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
          value: PLAINTEXT://kafka-cluster:9092
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: zookeeper-cluster1:2181
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-cluster
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: kafka-cluster
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: kafka-cluster
  ports:
  - name: kafka-cluster
    protocol: TCP
    port: 9092
    targetPort: 9092
```

Please suggest why service associated with Kafka on port 9092 is not working.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide output of `kubectl describe svc kafka-cluster`

Comment: Name:                     kafka-cluster
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=kafka-cluster
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=kafka-cluster
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.99.41.15
Port:                     kafka-cluster  9092/TCP
TargetPort:               9092/TCP
NodePort:                 kafka-cluster  30439/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.12:9092
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

Comment: @user2590014, have you tried to reach kafka Pod on the exposed port 30439?

Comment: The problem is likely `PLAINTEXT://kafka-cluster:9092`... Your host machine doesn't know how to resolve the address of `kafka-cluster`

Comment: Are your kafka pods running?

Comment: @mk_sta I tried service_ip:30439 i, but this is also not working

Comment: @cricket_007
I am able to run below command with service_name:9092 

     kubectl exec kafka-cluster-7fdcb9c6bb-kvcl6 -c kafka-cluster -i -t -- /opt/kafka_2.12-2.1.0/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh [ --broker-list kafka-cluster:9092  --topic smart-multi-meter ]

Comment: @Rico Yes kafka pod is running

Comment: Sure, if you are *within the pod / container*, you can access the address. Outside of the k8s network, then your services won't be able to connect as easily, and thus the advertised listener needs to know about the inside and outside network interfaces - ref https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: @user2590014, Your kafka service should be reachable outside K8s cluster by Node IP address and port 30439, find more information about NodePort service [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport).